# Not able to set form attribute value after post it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've the form and it looks like :

```
<form method="POST" action="create.php" data-id="0" class="postForm">
     <input type="hidden" id="#formId" value="1">
     <textarea class="formBodyText"></textarea>
     <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

The ajax call for this form is as :

```
$(document).on("submit",".postFrom",function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $.post("create.php",{'formId':$("#formId").val(),'formBodyText':$(this).find('.formBodyText').val()},function(data)
        {
            console.log("Return  : "+data);  //working fine , I mean getting expected result
            $(this).attr("data-id",data); // want to set the return data as form data-id attribute value 
        });
 });
```

the problem is with `$(this).attr("data-id",data);` , it's not setting the new value for the form.

what wrong with this code??

Comment: Try `$('.postFrom').attr("data-id",data);` And use $.ajax({ });

Comment: or returned  data is Json Array!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$(document).on("submit",".postFrom",function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var cache = $(this);  // get the form object here and use that inside of $.post
       $.post("create.php",
         {'formId':$("#formId").val(),
          'formBodyText':$(this).find('.formBodyText').val()
         },function(data)
            {
              console.log("Return  : "+data);  //working fine , I mean getting expected result
              cache.attr("data-id",data); // want to set the return data as form data-id attribute value 
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the ajax handler does not refer to the submitted form, you can use a closure variable like `$form` as shown below to fix this.

```
$(document).on("submit", ".postFrom", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post("create.php", {
        'formId': $("#formId").val(),
            'formBodyText': $(this).find('.formBodyText').val()
    }, function (data) {
        console.log("Return  : " + data); //working fine , I mean getting expected result
        $form.attr("data-id", data); // want to set the return data as form data-id attribute value 
    });
});
```

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context
>   option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified,
>   this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.